# Vector's 100 meter freestyle shape is hard to use!

Tags: mario-sonic-olympic-winter-games

In Mario and Sonic at the Olympic Games at Beijing for the DS, I was trying a mission that was for Vector. When the game began, I saw that Vector's shape pattern was a figure 8! It is very difficult to finish first with that pattern. Can anyone give me tips on how I can easily beat this mission?